# Wordpress theme layout problem

Tags: themes

In Drupal, we have blocks to customise the layout.

I am new in Wordpress, if I want to change my layout to the second image.

What should I do? Does wordpress have block region that can know how does the theme region looks like?

[image]

Comment: Is your theme custom? Some themes you download have these kind of settings in their options.

Comment: which theme you are using ? usually sidebars are there and try exploring options of placing widgets in sidebars from backend. It is not necessary to have such settings but it depends upon theme you are using.  You can design your own templates as well for categories, single and post pages etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally WP themes dont have block regions to place stuff inside. You have some themes with page builders, but what you want to achieve is mostly done by adding code to the header.php.